# How can hide ffmpeg output?

Tags: python-3

```
os.system('ffmpeg -ss 00:08:00 -i '+dAdi+' -frames:v 1 /home/pi/Desktop/filmekrangoruntuleri/'+egAdi+'2.jpg')
```

When I run my python(3) script through the terminal, I see the following outputs produced by ffmpeg, but how do I do this without appearing?

```
ffmpeg version 3.2.10-1~deb9u1+rpt2 Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 6.3.0 (Raspbian 6.3.0-18+rpi1+deb9u1) 20170516
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version='1~deb9u1+rpt2' --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf --incdir=/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libebur128 --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-omx-rpi --enable-mmal --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libiec61883 --arch=armhf --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libopencv --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  libavutil      55. 34.101 / 55. 34.101
  libavcodec     57. 64.101 / 57. 64.101
  libavformat    57. 56.101 / 57. 56.101
  libavdevice    57.  1.100 / 57.  1.100
  libavfilter     6. 65.100 /  6. 65.100
  libavresample   3.  1.  0 /  3.  1.  0
  libswscale      4.  2.100 /  4.  2.100
  libswresample   2.  3.100 /  2.  3.100
  libpostproc    54.  1.100 / 54.  1.100
Input #0, matroska,webm, from 'A.R.O.G.2008.m1080p.25fps.VP9.128kbit.AAC.mkv':
  Metadata:
    ENCODER         : Lavf58.18.104
  Duration: 02:02:20.27, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 2214 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: vp9 (Profile 0), yuv420p(tv, bt709/unknown/unknown), 1920x1080, SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 1k tbn, 1k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      DURATION        : 02:02:20.200000000
    Stream #0:1: Audio: aac (LC), 44100 Hz, mono, fltp (default)
    Metadata:
      HANDLER_NAME    : SoundHandler
      DURATION        : 02:02:20.269000000
[swscaler @ 0x15eb280] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
Output #0, image2, to '/home/pi/Desktop/filmekrangoruntuleri/A.R.O.G.2008.m1080p.25fps.VP9.128kbit.AAC.mkv_eg1.jpg':
```

Answer (score 1):

To avoid any output on the command line you can redirect it into the black hole `/dev/null` like this:

```
rpi ~$ my-python3-script >/dev/null 2>&1
```

This will redirect error output (stderr=2) to standard output (stdout=1) (`2>&1`) and then redirect the standard output to `/dev/null` so nothing will be shown even no error messages.

You can do it also direct in your script with:

```
os.system('ffmpeg -ss 00:08:00 -i '+dAdi+' -frames:v 1 /home/pi/Desktop/filmekrangoruntuleri/'+egAdi+'2.jpg >/dev/null 2>&1')
```

If you want to suppress success messages and only see the error messages you only send the standard messages into the black hole:

```
rpi ~$ my-python3-script >/dev/null
```

And wise versa, suppressing only error messages (makes less sense):

```
rpi ~$ my-python3-script 2>/dev/null
```

Comment: Thank you. So how do I capture only success or error messages?

Comment: Hi @HarunReşitÇ, does my answer help you? It would be nice if you could then accept it by clicking the tick on the left side. For your additional question I have updated the answer.